# Compatibility issue for Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, android-manifest, compatibility, samsung-mobile

I uploaded my application only for **1080*1920** and **720*1280** device resolutions over Google Play Store. But on Samsung's Galaxy S4, I'm unable to install this app from play store. The compatibility tag in the app's manifest I used for this device's resolutions is:

```
compatible-screens
screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal"
screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal"
compatible-screens
```

Comment: Why are you even doing this kind of very nit-picky filtering? Doesn't your app look ok on all the screens?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk No...i only need this app on above mentioned device resolutions.

Comment: You remind me of the web developer who blocks many third party internet browsers, not because his code doesn't work with those browsers, but because he was only hired to make his code work with Internet Explorer.

Comment: have you checked list of device that supports too your apk when you uploaded apk on playstore???